# LED and resistor in series on 24 V: resistor power rating

Tags: power, led, resistors

Can I connect a 1/10W 0603 resistor (4 kΩ) and a 0603 LED (I = 5 mA) to a 24 VDC supply?

Will the resistor burn out in this connection?

Comment: looks like you're over-stressing the rated LED current as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get 5 mA with a 4 kΩ resistor, the voltage drop across the resistor is I · R = 5 mA · 4000 = 20 V.

The voltage drop across the LED would then be 24 - 20 = 4 V. This seems high: is 4 V what you were going for?

P = V · I, so the resistor dissipates 20 · 0.005 = 0.1 W. That is exactly the rating you mention, but I would go for one that has some headroom.

If you were going for a LED voltage drop of, say, 2 V, then the resistor has to drop 24 - 2 = 22 V. Current will then be V/R = 22/4000 = 5.5 mA, and the resistor will dissipate 22 V · 0.0055 A = 0.12 W, which is too much, and it will eventually burn out.

You should find the LED's forward voltage drop and then recalculate the resistor's value and power rating.

Answer (score 1):

The LED will drop maybe 2 volts across its terminals hence the resistor will see about 22 volts. The power dissipated by a 4 kΩ resistor with 22 volts across it is \$\frac{22^2}{4000}\$ = 0.121 watts. That's more than 0.1 watts so, when you ask this...

> *Will the resistor burn out in this connection?*

You are definitely over-stressing the resistor and, it may scorch and fail if used continuously.

Answer (score 1):

The resistor will probably not "burn out", but it will run hot and may eventually fail.

If you have a 24V source, and want to run 5mA through an LED, you can follow a fairly simple procedure:

1. Calculate the voltage across the current limiting resistor.  This is the supply voltage minus the LED voltage.  You can get the LED voltage from its data sheet, but for this case you can also just estimate.  White and blue LEDs typically run around 2.5-3.0 volts, red is about 1.8, green somewhere in between.  Let's assume a blue LED at 3V.  So 24V-3V = 21V across the current limiting resistor.
2. Calculate the resistance.  I'm assuming that you want 5mA since you call it a 5mA LED.  You can always use less than the maximum current if you don't need max brightness.  So 21V/5mA = 4200 ohms.  Your 4K is pretty close, but I'd be inclined to use something like 4.7K unless I was trying to get the absolute maximum possible brightness.
3. Calculate the resistor power dissipation.  21V * 5mA = 0.105 watts.  A 1/10 watt resistor will survive at 0.105 watts in most situations, but as a general rule I like to run resistors at half or less of their rated dissipation.  So I'd be looking for a resistor rated at 0.2W or more.

The actual power handling of a resistor (especially a surface mount resistor) is determined by lots of things besides the resistor itself.  How big are the traces connected to the resistor?  They will conduct away heat.  Are there other heat dissipating components nearby?  What is your ambient temperature?  There is a big difference between a 22 deg C office or medical application and a 60 dec C industrial controls cabinet.  The 2:1 derate that I recommend as a general rule works in most cases; if you are dealing with extreme situations you need to be aware of that and adjust accordingly.